# Probability that each queen is drawn before the king of the same suit, given 4 kings and 4 queens in a deck

Tags: probability, combinatorics, conditional-probability

I am trying to solve the problem from the Hugh Gordon's "Discrete Probability" book (Ch.3, problem 43.c)

**Question**

We select from a deck of cards the four kings and the four queens. From these eight cards, we draw one card at a time, without replacement, until all eight cards have been drawn. Find the probability that each queen is drawn before the king of each suit.

**My attempt of a solution**

I realize that there are $8!$ possible arrangements of four kings and four queens. My initial reaction was that if I treat each pair of QK of the respective suit as the distinct unit then I can arrange the 4 pairs in $4!$ ways . The answer at the back of a book is $1/16$, which suggests that my estimate of $p=\frac{4!}{8!}$ does not count additional options, such as the case $QsQcQhQdKcKdKsKh$, where all queens precede all kings, which happens in $4!\cdot 4!$ ways. But there are other cases. What would be the easiest way to group the cases and count them or am I missing a more trivial approach to this?

**Update**
I was inspired to reconsider the problem by watching the reasoning from
[AOPS probability of brother and sister sitting together in a row](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p3jSASdniSE&list=LL&index=3)

Let's focus first on the specific suit, say clubs, and let's treat the remaining distinct cards separately. We have $Qc$ and $Kc$ and the remaining $6$ cards. There are 8 slots that correspond to the order of the draw. Now, in any arrangement of the $6$ remaining non-club cards there will be $2$ slots left "waiting" to be filled by $Qc$ and $Kc$. Vividly, for each such arrangement, either the $Qc$ comes before $Kc$, or the vice versa. Thus, the probability that the $Qc$ comes before $Kc$ is $\frac{1}{2}$.
Of course, the same analysis is true regardless of a suit. Furthermore, if we assume the independence of all these arrangements, then the probability that each queen is drawn before the king of each suit, i.e., the probability of all of the 4 events happening together, is the product of the above probabilities, or $p=(\frac{1}{2})^4=1/16$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: The comment by @jlammy is important. We can't tell whether you misunderstood the question (maybe "each queen is drawn before the king of ** the same** suit" would be clearer), or whether you made a mathematical mistake, or what. The book's answer $1/16$ is correct.

Comment: "My initial reaction was that if I treat each pair of QK of the respective suit as the distinct unit then I can arrange the 4 pairs in 4! ways"  But that assumes the QK pairs must be adjecent.  What if you have Q(hearts),Q(spade), K(heart), K(spade).  You have way undercounted as you have QQQQKKKK, QQQKQKKK, QQQKKQKK, etc. to all be the same.

Comment: Any..... In half the arrangements the Queen of each suit comes before the King of the suit, and in half the arrangements the King comes first.  So 1/2 will have the Q hearts come before the K of hearts, and half of *those* will have the Q spade before the K spade, and so on.  So it will by $(\frac 12)^4$.

Comment: Or... there are $8\choose 2$ ways to place the queen and king of hearts.  Of the remaining $6$ spaces there are ${8\choose 2}\cdot {6\choose 2}$ ways to places the hearts and the spades.  And so on.  So there are ${8\choose 2}\cdot{6\choose 2}\cdot {4\choose 2}\cdot {2\choose 2}$ ways to arrange the cards so that the queen of each suit is before the king of the suit (regardless as to the other suits).  .... and it's easy to verify that ${8\choose 2}\cdot{6\choose 2}\cdot {4\choose 2}\cdot {2\choose 2}=\frac {8!}{16}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In half the cases the Q of spades comes before the K of spades and in half the cases it's the other way around.

And in half of the cases where the Q of spades comes before the K spades, we will have the Q clubs come before the K of clubs.

So in one-fourth of the cases we will have the Q of spades before the K of spades and we will have the Q of clubs before the K of clubs.  In 3/4 of the cases one or the other will fail to happen.  Now we don't give an At's Rass about whether the the order is QsKsQcKc or QsQcKsKc or QsQcKcKs$ or QcQsKsKc or whetever.... all we care about is that we have --Qs--Ks-- (where - is zero or more cards) and --Qc--Kc--- and we don't care about how the spades interact with the clubs.

As for any arrangement of the 6 other cards will have *exactly* half with the Q of a specific suit before the K of that suit (and the other half will have the K before the Q) we will have $(\frac 12)^4$ of the $8!$ possible arrangements with each the queens before the specific kings.

.....

Or to be more calculating.

There are ${8\choose 2}$ ways of selecting the $2$ spaces for the SPADES.  You must place the Queen in the first place and the King in the second.

There are ${6\choose 2}$ ways of selecting the $2$ spaces from the remaining $6$ spaces for the CLUBS. and ${4\choose 2}$ ways of selecting spaces from the $4$ remaining spaces for the diamonds. ANd $2\choose 2$ ways for the HEARTS.

That is ${8\choose 2}{6\choose 2}{4\choose 2}{2\choose 2}$ out of $8!$ ways to do it

$\frac {{8\choose 2}{6\choose 2}{4\choose 2}{2\choose 2}}{8!} =$

$\frac {\frac {8!}{6!2!}\frac {6!}{4!2!}\frac {4!}{2!2!}\frac {2!}{0!2!}}{8!}=$

$\require{cancel)}$

$\frac {\frac {\cancel{8!}}{\cancel{6!}2!}\frac {\cancel{6!}}{\cancel{4!}2!}\frac {\cancel{4!}}{\cancel{2!}2!}\frac {\cancel{2!}}{0!2!}}{\cancel{8!}}=$

$\frac 1{16}$